# Displaying mysql results as an object?

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays, object

If I have a database with the structure:

```
___id_____|____value____
   1      |    value1
   2      |    value2
   3      |    value3
```

How can I pull data from this MySQL database in PHP and have it formatted like this:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [value] => value1 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 2 [value] => value2 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 3 [value] => value3 ) )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **mysql_fetch_object()** function instead of **mysql_fetch_array()** and manually create new objects.

Read more about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php

Comment: Wow.  I had completely forgotten about that function.  Even easier than casting a result array.  +1.